# Number of functions $f: X \to X$ with $k$ being the minimal such that $f^k(a) = b$

Tags: combinatorics

With some notations added, I am trying to calculate $\Psi_X$ where:

Given finite set $X$ define $\Psi_X: X \times X \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$

where $\Psi_X(a, b, k)$ is the number of functions $f: X \to X$ such that $k$ is the minimal with $f^k(a) = b$ where the power of $f$ is in composition context i.e, $f^3(a) = f(f(f(a)))$.

If we take for example $k=2$ and $X = \{ x_1, x_2, x_3 \}$ then $\Psi_X(x_1,x_2,2) = 3$

This is since $f(x_1)$ can not be $x_2$ since it contradicts the minimality of $k=2$ and $f(x_1)$ can not be $x_1$ becuase then $f^2(x_1) \neq x_2$ hence we must have $f(x_1) = x_3$ and hence $f(x_3) = x_2$ and so $f(x_2)$ can be any of the three values.

As we can notice, $\Psi_X$ is apathetic to the choice of $x_1, x_2 \in X$ so we can more conveniently define $\Psi_X: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. Generalizing this, we can define $\Psi: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ to be $\Psi(n,k) = \Psi_{\{1,2,\dots,n\}}(k)$ which is equal to $\Psi_X(k)$ for all $|X| = n$.

> So this goes down to calculating $\Psi: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.

By the example above, we can see $\Psi(3,2) = 3$.

It is easy to see that $\Psi(n,1) = n^{n-1}$ because we can freely define the functions except for one element.

By looking at these 2 examples only I thought we might have $\Psi(n,k) = n^{n-k}$ but this is not the case for all $n,k$:

For example, if we calculate for $n=4$ and $k=3$ then denote for convenience $X = \{x_1, x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ and solve $\Psi_X(x_1,x_4,3)$ So we know $f(x_1) \in \{x_2,x_3 \}$. Assume first case is $f(x_1) = x_2$, then $f(x_2) \in \{x_1,x_3\}$. We can notice here that $f(x_2) = x_1$ would lead to $f^3(x_1) \neq x_4$ so we must have $f(x_2) = x_3$ and hence $f(x_3) = x_4$ so that we have $f^3(x_1) = x_4$ indeed. here we have 4 choices for $x_4$. The second case is symmetric and disjoint so we get $8$ functions in total. Hence, for $n=4,k=3$ we get a different form which is $\Psi(n,k)=2n^{n-k}$

My next guess was $\Psi(n,k) = d(n,k)n^{n-k}$ for some function $d(n,k)$

One more example shows:

For $X = \{x_1, x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ and $\Psi_X(x_1,x_4,2)$ we get: $f(x_1) \in \{x_2,x_3 \}$. First case is $f(x_1) = x_2$ so we must have $f(x_2) = x_4$. here we have 4 choices for $x_3$ and 4 for $x_4$ so we get 16 functions in total in this case. The second case is disjoint and symmetric so we get a total of $32$ functions. which again gives the form $\Psi(n,k) = 2n^{n-k}$ with $n=4,k=2$

I guess this could be some elementary combinatorics formula but not sure how to proceed to find it. Any help or a full answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't be entirely apathetic about the choices of $x_1,x_2$: for example, for $[3]=\{1,2,3\}$, we get $\Psi_{[3]}(1,1,2)=6$ (assuming that we ignore that $f^0(1)=1$) while $\Psi_{[3]}(1,2,2)=3$. The latter uses the argument you presented, but the former exposes that your constraints $f(x_1)\neq x_2$ and $f(x_1)\neq x_1$ coincide when $x_1=x_2$. Beyond checking if $x_1=x_2$, your definition of $\Psi$ does not care about how these variables are assigned.

Let's define the function $\Psi_1:\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ which has $\Psi_1(n,k)$ counting the number of functions $f:[n]\to[n]$ with $k>0$ minimal so that $f^k(1)=1$.
Therefore, the choices $1\mapsto a_1\mapsto a_2\mapsto\dots\mapsto a_{k-1}\mapsto1$ describing the orbit of $1$ under $f$ have to all be distinct elements of $[n]\setminus\{1\}$.
There are $\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}$ ways of picking the $a_i$'s in sequence.

For the remaining $n-k$ elements of $[n]$ (namely, those in $[n]\setminus\{1,a_1,\dots,a_{k-1}\}$), we are free to define $f$ however we please, which gives us $n^{n-k}$ choices.
In total, this gives us $\Psi_1(n,k) = \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}n^{n-k}$.

- notice that $\Psi_1(3,2)=6$ and not $3$, like I mentioned earlier.

On the other hand, the function $\Psi:\Bbb N_{>1}\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ that you defined can be rephrased as $\Psi(n,k)$ counting the number of functions $f:[n]\to[n]$ with $k$ minimal such that $f(1)=2$. We can compute this similarly.
Now, we have a sequence $1\mapsto a_1\mapsto\dots\mapsto a_{k-1}\mapsto2$ with $a_i$ chosen from $[n]\setminus\{1,2\}$. This leaves $\frac{(n-2)!}{(n-k-1)!}$ ways of choosing the $a_i$.

However, now we are free to define the behaviour of $f$ on $[n]\setminus\{1,a_1,\dots,a_{k-1}\}$ however we like (notice that this set *includes* the number $2$). This is a set of $n-k$ elements and gives us $n^{n-k}$ choices total.
Therefore, the formula is

> $$
> \Psi(n,k) = \frac{(n-2)!}{(n-k-1)!}n^{n-k}
> $$

Comparing against your examples:

- here, $\Psi(3,2)=3$ like you said
- $\Psi(n,1)=n^{n-1}$ as before
- $\Psi(4,2)=\frac{2!}{1!}4^2 = 2n^{n-k}$ setting $n=4$ and $k=2$